# Error installing mod_wsgi from source

Tags: python, apache, mod-wsgi

I installed `apr-1.5.2`, `apr-util-1.5.4`, `apr-iconv-1.2.1`, and `httpd-2.4.25` all by building it from source. Using the default settings. But every time I tries to build mod_wsgi, it always show this error. I tried what other answers suggested but nothing helped.

I'm running Mac OSX with python 3 and installed Xcode-select just as the installation guide said I should. But I don't have Xcode(No where in the installation guide said that I need to). How can I not get this error?

```
$./configure
checking for apxs2... no
checking for apxs... /usr/sbin/apxs
apxs:Error: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/OSX10.12.xctoolchain/usr/local/bin/apr-1-config not found!.
apxs:Error: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/OSX10.12.xctoolchain/usr/local/bin/apr-1-config not found!.
cat: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/OSX10.12.xctoolchain/usr/local/share/apr-1/build-1/libtool: No such file or directory
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking for prctl... no
checking Apache version... apxs:Error: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/OSX10.12.xctoolchain/usr/local/bin/apr-1-config not found!.
apxs:Error: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/OSX10.12.xctoolchain/usr/local/bin/apr-1-config not found!.
apxs:Error: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/OSX10.12.xctoolchain/usr/local/bin/apr-1-config not found!.
2.4.23
apxs:Error: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/OSX10.12.xctoolchain/usr/local/bin/apr-1-config not found!.
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating Makefile
```

If I use pip, I also get the same error...

```
$pip3 install mod_wsgi
Collecting mod_wsgi
  Using cached mod_wsgi-4.5.14.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/private/var/folders/7l/3hjlgnpj3mdf61ptzzdwtzf80000gn/T/pip-build-yvl7rbe8/mod-wsgi/setup.py", line 298, in <module>
        APR_INCLUDES = get_apr_includes().split()
      File "/private/var/folders/7l/3hjlgnpj3mdf61ptzzdwtzf80000gn/T/pip-build-yvl7rbe8/mod-wsgi/setup.py", line 259, in get_apr_includes
        stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 707, in __init__
        restore_signals, start_new_session)
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 1326, in _execute_child
        raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg)
    FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/OSX10.12.xctoolchain/usr/local/bin/apr-1-config'

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/7l/3hjlgnpj3mdf61ptzzdwtzf80000gn/T/pip-build-yvl7rbe8/mod-wsgi/
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `pip` installable mod_wsgi as explained in:

- https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mod_wsgi

if using MacOS X.

You can no longer use config/make/make install method on MacOS X as Apple no longer ship the bits required for it to work.

Once installed using `pip`, follow steps as explained in section "Connecting into Apache installation" to hook it into Apache.

Comment: Still the same error:( Sorry, I forgot to add that I already tried pip

Comment: Does the directory ``/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain`` exist in your machine?

Comment: And if that directory does exist, where under that is the directory ``MacOSX.sdk``.

Comment: No, I don't even have Xcode.app. Don't know why it wanted to go there

Comment: You are definite that you have run ``xcode-select --install``? It may the case you do have to install XCode now due to how Apple has broken things.

Comment: yes I did exactly that `xcode-select --install`. So I have to also install the gigantic sized xCode? :(

Comment: Probably. The ``xcode-select`` command would install Apache header files under ``/usr/include`` but it doesn't anymore, so must come from Xcode. Your only other option is not to use Apple Apache and install Apache from HomeBrew or using a ``pip`` installable version of Apache I provide. Are you only wanting this for development, or do you really want to permanently set up Apache on your machine and have it visible from outside of your computer?

Comment: Well...I wanted to permanently setup apache...anyways, thanks for your extended help

Comment: Your only option besides installing XCode is to use ``pip install mod_wsgi-httpd`` and then ``pip install mod_wsgi`` and then use ``mod_wsgi-express``. That will work from command line. You can then use the ``setup-server`` option to create files that you would need to wrap in Apple magic to start server on system boot etc. Except for Apple specific bits, is documented on PyPi page.

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton its not working for me i had followed as you explained and i am getting  -bash: mod_wsgi-express: command not found

Comment: @Vaisakh Create a separate question clearly explaining what you have done and what the problem is. Don't use comments to ask a new question or ask for debugging help.

Answer (score 0):

You can alternatively use `homebrew` to install it. Use the following command. It'll install all the dependencies and finally mod_wsgi

`brew install mod_wsgi --with-brewed-httpd24`

Comment: Unfortunately distributions from people such as HomeBrew, and Linux OS's are usually quite out of date and not recommended they be used.

Comment: Well, I happen to have different opinion in case of homebrew. I agree for Linux OSs.

Comment: One reason why will grant that HomeBrew can be better option is if using Python 3.6, using HomeBrew Apache as well and need mod_ssl in Apache. This combination doesn't work with Apple Apache as Python 3.6 uses its own SSL libraries. Even then, still easier enough to use ``pip install mod_wsgi`` method to install mod_wsgi.